# casting to XML by default parsing HTML tags too

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML document which contains this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if &quot;server&quot; is set to default.</description>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

```bsh
$gcXML = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp.xml"
Write-Output $gcXML
```

The `&quot;` are preserved in the code above, but not in the code below:

```bsh
$xdoc = [xml] $gcXML
$xdoc.'web-app'.'context-param'.'description'
```

Here `&quot;` is being parsed as `"`, which I don't want. Output is:

> Only applicable if "server" is set to default.

How can I preserve the `&quot;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might re-encode the string if that's what you need and you do not wish to (or cannot) change the XML content:

```
# Load the System.Web assembly
Add-Type -Assembly System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($xdoc.'web-app'.'context-param'.'description')
```

Versions of PowerShell older than 5 may need additional parentheses surrounding a complex value:

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode(($xdoc.'web-app'.'context-param'.'description'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In XML, `&quot;` is semantically the same as `"` in element content.

If the raw text you intend to store is literally `Only applicable if &quot;server&quot; is set to default.` and not `Only applicable if "server" is set to default.`, then the ampersand must be escaped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if &amp;quot;server&amp;quot; is set to default.</description>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```